# Unable to import state of a country in odoo8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to import new customers using import option available in the user interface.When I try to import states of USA everything works fine and import is successful,but when I try to import a customer from India with some indian state which is already existing in database it is giving me error as "No matching record found".Code for Usa is "us" and for India it is "in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data files use XML Ids to reference records in other tables. In the case of countries, these are `base.XX` where XX is the country code.

If you're importing a CSV file, make sure that column is named `country_id:id` and try the value `base.in` for India and `base.us` for the USA.